# How did the The Fukushima Nuclear Disaster affect Japan's vegetation?

Tags: earthquakes, tsunami

I am working on an important project please help!

Comment: What have you found out so far from your research?

Comment: I don't know whether EarthScience has a great number of biological scientists, though I suspect we'll try to help as best we can from our various knowledge and Googling given a little input as to what you have uncovered so far.  But you may well find Biology SE to be more informed overall on the subject

Comment: Well... nothing too much I just found articles about how the nuclear waste will affect the forests.... I want to know How and Why....

Comment: The effect was probably pretty minimal. Look at Chernobyl, which released far more radiation that Fukishima. The Chernobyl exclusion zone is now a hotspot for biodiversity, precisely because nobody has been there in the past 30 years. People do far more damage to the environment than low level radiation.

Comment: I don't know much about why, but I've read that plants are far more susceptible to obvious visible changes when exposed to radiation than animals.   You don't get 3-eyed fish (at least, not often), but you do get weird plants.   Biology is probably better for this question.

Comment: I agree that you probably will have to incorporate studies of other sites that have been subject to radiation releases. Impacts on vegetation typically aren't of highest importance when responding to radioactive emergencies. I suggest you search for articles in Environmental Science and Technology and the Journal of Radioanalytical and Nuclear Chemistry. I don't think you will find any significant effects so you may want to expand your topic to deal with food-chain uptake like iodine-139 from local fallout to cattle ingestion and into milk. You might find some data on seaweed levels.

Comment: @bon: Re Chernobyl, change that to "almost nobody".  There are still people living in the exclusion zone, and have been since the accident.  Some of them are people who survived both Hitler and Stalin: a little radiation doesn't bother them.